# Add the installation prefix of "rslidar_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin-make, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner in ROS, and I'm using the version of ROS for windows. ros package for robosense lidar So I'm in windows. This is done through a CMD window. But I've met 2 problem:

1. how to install libpcap-dev in ROS for windows
2. when compiling, I encounter the following problem, I put the error trace below, how to fix it

   ```
    CMake Error at C:/opt/ros/melodic/x64/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
      Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rslidar_msgs" with
      any of the following names:

        rslidar_msgsConfig.cmake
        rslidar_msgs-config.cmake

      Add the installation prefix of "rslidar_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
      "rslidar_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
      "rslidar_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
      has been installed.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
   ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354677/add-the-installation-prefix-of-%22rslidar_msgs%22-to-cmake_prefix_path/) by [rechuin](https://answers.ros.org/users/55716/rechuin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@rechuin It means you will need to git clone the rslidar_msgs' repository into your workspace, so that catkin can find and build it. Alternatively, you can check out [this](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/UsingROSonWindows.html), where it documents the generic workflow how one to consume a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [Sean Yen](https://answers.ros.org/users/37768/sean-yen/) with karma: 16 on 2020-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2